# AJAX/jQuery and CRUD operations with MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

So I'm a pretty new MVC developer, and I'm having a little trouble with a specific functionality.

I have these classes:

```
public class User
{

    public int UserId{ get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public bool LogicalDelete { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Phone> Phone{ get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EventList> Event{ get; set; }
}

public class Phone
{
    public int PhoneId{ get; set; }
    public string Phone{ get; set; }
    public bool Mobile{ get; set; }
    public int UserId{ get; set; }
    public virtual UserClass User { get; set; }
}
```

What I´m trying to do is when I go to the Edit view of the User have a button that lets me add both a new Phone, or a number of phones separated by commas, to that specific user using an AJAX post script.

So far I've been using this for the single phone approach:

```
function Add() {
    var res = validate();
    if (res == false) {
        return false;
    }
    var ph = {
        UserId: $('#UserId').val(),
        FirstName: $('#Phone').val(),
        LastName: $('#Mobile').val(),
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: "/User/Edit",
        data: JSON.stringify(ph),
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
           loadData();
        },
        error: function (errormessage) {
            alert(errormessage.responseText);
        }
    });
```

And, in the `UserController`:

```
public JsonResult Add(Phone ph)
{
    return Json(myDb.Add(ph), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The main problem I have is that I can´t pass the specific´s user Id to the controller from the Edit views model. I did some testing with adding an user from the View to the database and I was able to do it, but when I try to access the navigation property I´m not able to either list the Telephones, or add a new one.

What am I missing?

Comment: url in ajax is `/User/Edit` but your controller is Add

Comment: Also, `Add` should be `httppost` which should be `denyGet` as well

Comment: Your `Phone` class does not have a property named `UserId` (or properties named `FirstName`, `LastName` and `State`, although `UserClass` contains 3 of those properties)

Comment: Certainly `UserId` property in `UserClass` doesn't match with `UsuarioId` in `Phone` even they have same meaning in different languages (i.e. English & Spanish), it still means different properties. Also your controller action method probably not marked with `HttpPostAttribute`, which required by AJAX call.

Comment: I missed the translation, I´ll edit it right now to reflect the correct structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use an Ajax form?

```
<div id="userDetails">
 @* All other user details *@
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddPhone", null, new AjaxOptions()
    {
        HttpMethod = "Post",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        UpdateTargetId = "userDetails",           
    }, null))
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserId)
        <input type="text" id="phone" />
        <select id="phoneType">
            <option value="home">Home</option>
            <option value="cell">Cell</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit">Add Phone</button>
    }
</div>


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddPhone(int UserId, string phone, string phoneType)
{
//Add phone using userId, phone, & phoneType
...

//Return view with model (user object) to update page with added phone
return View("UserView", UserObject);
}
```

Comment: Hello, I´ve been trying to implement your solution, but I get the error:
"The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'UserId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' " when I try to press the submit button. I think I dont understand how to send the UserId to the controller from the Ajax form.

Comment: I'm assuming that your model contains a user id somewhere... so this part @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserId) is to include that user id in the form post. I don't know how your model has the user id in order to get it. It could be Model.UserId, Model.User.UserId... however you access User Id in your model.

Answer (score 0):

```
var ph = {
        UserId: $('#UserId').val(),
        FirstName: $('#Phone').val(),
        LastName: $('#Mobile').val(),
    };
```

should be changed to

```
  var ph = {
            UserId: parseInt($('#UserId').val()),
            Phone: $('#Phone').val(),
            Mobile: $('#Mobile').val(),
        };
```

Currently your phone class in the api call has empty phone string (if this object is even being casted to Phone class), if your view have an input field with "#UserId" it should pass , through i would advise to parse the value to integer before sending the data,  the Mobile field is Boolean .val() returns true or false?

Accessing data in navigation properties is another matter, you should check if it exists in the appropriate tables, and if so is it loaded correctly (some data access framework requires you to specifically mention the navigation property to load it) for example in some config of EntityFramework it requires to do something like that:

```
User user = dbContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == 1).Include("Phones");
```

where "Phones" is the navigation property to the list.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using an Ajax.BeginForm to resolve this, in the following way:

```
    <div id ="userDetails">

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddPhone", null, new AjaxOptions()
    {
        HttpMethod = "Post",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        UpdateTargetId = "userDetails",           
    }, null))
    {
        @Html.Hidden("UserId", prod.UserId)
        string Phone = "";
        @Html.EditorFor(x=>Phone) 
        @Html.DropDownList("phoneType", ViewData["telType"] as SelectList)
        string phone1 = "";
        <button  type="submit" >AddPhone</button>
    }
    </div>
```

Thanks a lot @Barry for the help. I ended up sending the UserId through ViewData to the View for the Ajax form.